# How to ignore directory on git diff --no-index?

Tags: git, git-diff

I am trying to create a colorized diff between two folders in the same repository (This may be the totally wrong approach).

I believe one way of achieving this is through `git diff --no-index folder1 folder2` and it will automatically create a patch for you (Cool).

However, the diff also includes (as one might expect), all of the `.gitignore`'d files as well.

```
folder1
  node_modules
  src/
  .gitignore
  package.json
  README.md

folder2
  node_modules
  src/
  .gitignore
  package.json
  README.md
```

I would like to ignore `node_modules`.

Possibilities? Alternatives?

Comment: Did you find something that worked? I have a related conundrum.

Comment: Here some attempt of doing that in bash, by using the `.gitignore` file from folder1 to filter out undesired paths: `src=folder1 dst=folder2; { { git diff --no-index --no-renames --name-only -- "$src" "$dst" | sed '/^\/dev\/null$/d;s~^[^/]*/~~;/^[^/]*\.git\//d' | sort -u | tee /dev/stderr; } | git -C "$src" check-ignore --stdin; } |& uniq -u | while read file; do f1="$src/$file" f2="$dst/$file"; git diff --no-index --no-renames -- "$([ -e "$f1" ] && echo "$f1" || echo /dev/null)" "$([ -e "$f2" ] && echo "$f2" || echo /dev/null)"; done`

Answer (score 1):

Cheaty version:

```bash
git diff $(git commit-tree -m '' @:folder1) $(git commit-tree -m '' @:folder2)
```

which makes an on-the-fly commit for each tree (as they were on checkout) and diffs the two commits.

You can easily make scratch commits if you want to do this for the current worktree contents,

```bash
( export GIT_INDEX_FILE=.git/scratch-index
  git add .
  temp=`git write-tree`
  git diff $(git commit-tree -m '' $temp:folder1) $(git commit-tree -m '' $temp:folder2)
)
```

and for finer control over what you're using you can pipe `git ls-files` with whatever pathspecs you want to `git update-index --add --stdin`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use the `assume-unchanged` flag
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index

#### --[no-]assume-unchanged

> When this flag is specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated.
>   Instead, this option sets/unsets the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths.
>
> When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, the user promises not to change the file and allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index. If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git. This is sometimes helpful when working with a big project on a filesystem that has very slow lstat(2) system call (e.g. cifs).
>
> Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually.

[image]

Comment: I don't quite follow how this can be used in conjunction and or replacement to the diff?

Comment: set the files inside your .gitignore with this flag

Comment: fatal: Unable to mark file … (When trying to execute `git update-index --[no-]assume-unchanged node_modules`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a simple solution as one would hope, but two somewhat unconventional yet easy alternatives.

1. If you can do without the ignored files, just clean them from the repo before executing the diff:

```sh
# -x means that files from the .gitignore will also be cleaned
# --interactive shows you what will be deleted before doing so
git clean -x --interactive folder1 folder2

# now the files simply don't exist any more
git diff --no-index folder1 folder2
```

2. Another way to achieve this without having to permanently delete the ignored files would be to quickly clone the repo locally:

```sh
cd ..
git clone original-directory clone-of-repo

cd clone-of-repo
# in the clone, ignored files are naturally not included
git diff --no-index folder1 folder2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you care about comparing the two *versioned* contents of the directories (e.g : the contents of `dir1/` and `dir2/` in the current commit, without taking into account whatever modifications there could be in the index or the worktree), you can ask `git diff` to compare two *trees* already written in your repo :

```
# 'HEAD:dir1' is a syntax to designate the tree object stored at path 'dir1'
# in the current active commit ('HEAD')
git diff HEAD:dir1 HEAD:dir2
```

This will compare only the content tracked by git (hence: the `.gitignore`d content, which isn't written at all in the repo, will not show up)

---

If you also want to compare the modifications in the index or the worktree while respecting `.gitignore` rules, you may use several tricks to have `git` create that tree :

- if you want to compare the staged content :

`git write-tree` will create a tree object from the staged content

```
treehash=$(git write-tree)
git diff ${treehash}:dir1/ ${treehash}:dir2/
```

- if you want to compare the worktree content on tracked files :

you may use `git stash create` to quickly have a tree which contains that content

```
hash=$(git stash create)
git diff ${hash}:dir1/ ${hash}:dir2/
```

(note that `git stash *create*` is not the same as `git stash` or `git stash push`, it creates the structure that is stored in the stash but doesn't update the stash with it)