# How to exclude files & directories from git diff --no-index

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

How do I exclude files & directories from `git diff --no-index`?

For example, I want to show the differences between two directories `project1` & `project2` while ignoring their top-level `.git` directories (`project1/.git` & `project2/.git`) and all their `.DS_Store` files.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415100/want-to-exclude-file-from-git-diff

Comment: @jjmerelo I tried `diff`, but it doesn't have `--color-words`.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53471209/241211, https://stackoverflow.com/q/34776768/241211

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you asked for, but it might give you the results you want: Add `project2` as a remote of `project1` and just `git diff` their `HEAD`s.

```sh
git remote add other ../project2/.git
git fetch other

# Perform the diff
git diff other/HEAD
```

If your `project2` is not already a Git repo, you can temporarily make it one (hat tip to [Josiah Yoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048186/josiah-yoder) for his [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969016/how-to-exclude-files-directories-from-git-diff-no-index/50606259?noredirect=1#comment112038523_50606259)):

```sh
# Set up project2 repo
cd ../project2
git init
git add .

# Add as remote from project1
cd ../project1
git remote add other ../project2/.git
git fetch other

# Perform the diff
git diff other/master

# Clean up
git remote remove other
cd ../project2
rm -r .git
```

Comment: Can't you just do a temporary `git init; git add .` in the non-repo and then `rm -r .git` in the non-repo dir when you are done with the diff?

Comment: By the way, the add is done with `git remote add other path/to/project2/.git`, then `git fetch other`, and `git diff other/master`.  In the case of a non-repo, I would perform these commands from the non-repo.