# git diff noindex exclude files

Tags: git, diff

Does any one how to exclude files when comparing folders with git diff --no-index ? It seems this option

```
':(exclude)*.min.css'
```

does not work with no-index (outside working tree)

Comment: Copy the trees to be diffed to new trees, and remove the files you don't want. Not pretty but will do the trick.

Comment: Nominal duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34776768/241211

Answer (score 7):

The [pathspec  :(exclude) and its short form :! or :^](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21079437/6309) is available only within a Git working tree.

So:

- either, as commented, you can put it in a (temporary) git local repo (git init . + git add) or
- you would need to do your `git diff --no-index` in a [`find -exec` command with exclude directives](https://superuser.com/a/397325/141).

Comment: Is it documented that pathspecs are only available within a Git working tree?  Does this mean pathspecs are NEVER available with --no-index, even if the command is run from within a Git working tree?

Comment: @JosiahYoder Not sure actually: what did you try?

Comment: I tried cd'ing into one of the repos to be compared, then tried creating a temporary git repo.  Both used `--no-index`, and both simply showed usage .  I think `--no-index` simply doesn't work with `:!.git`

Comment: In the end, I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50606259/1048186) to a very similar question, which recommended making one repo a remote of the other.

Comment: @VonC

I dont think the second option you mentioned works as you think it does.

At least the following doesn't work for me:

    `find . -name '*.txt' -exec git diff --stat --no-index git_test1/*.txt git_test2/*.txt \;`

Any tipps or snippets for the second option would be appreciated.

Comment: @SamFed The second option was about using exclude directive. I don't see them in your command. Can you ask a separate question, with more details on your current setup? ( OS, shell, Git version)